# Output an object from an object array to a label in windows forms

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, object

I have 2 classes, Seats and Movie. Seats is my abstract class. 
I made an array of objects `Seats[,] users = new Seats[5, 5];` in Movie. 
When a user enters their name and seat number I populate the object array but I do not know how to output the object again. I have tried to output it using `testLabel.Text = users[i, j].ToString();`
My full code of the button is below.

```
public String tempName = "";
        public Int32 tempNum = 0;
        public Boolean tempOccupy = false;

        public Int32 i = 0;
        public Int32 j = 0;

        Seats[,] users = new Seats[5, 5];
        public Bookings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tempName = textBox1.Text;
            tempNum = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            tempOccupy = true;

            Seats p1 = new Seats(tempName, tempNum, tempOccupy);


            while (i != 4 && j != 4)
            {
                if (i == 4)
                {
                    i++;
                    users[i, j] = p1;
                }
                users[i, j] = p1;
                j++;
            }

            testLabel.Text = users[i, j].ToString();

        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to print all of them on a single label? maybe comma separated?

Comment: I was just testing with one object for now with a testLabel. The object has two attributes Name and SeatNumber. I'm not sure how to print both those attributes onto a label.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `ToString()` method in `Seats`

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return $"{Name} {SeatNumber}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you want to print them all into a label and it's a complex object you can override ToString() method in Seats objects or you can select the attributes you want to print concatenating them :

```
testLabel.Text = users[i, j].SeatsAttributeName +" "+ users[i, j].SeatsAttributeOccupy;
```

Just try here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/XojUnP

Comment: I can see how this would work but I think my population of the object array is incorrect when the button is pressed. There are two text boxes, one for name, one for seat number and these attributes are applied to an object when the button is pressed but I think it is because my population is incorrect because I am getting a System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error

Comment: yes, that's because you are populating the matrix wrong. Using while is only populating a few cells. If you feel more comfortable you can use 2 nested "for loops"